# How do i filter db records by date considering current user timezone?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

The records' date/time in DB are stored in UTC format. Model goes like this:

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    deal = models.ForeignKey(Deal)
    user_of_action = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    description = models.TextField()
    affected_fields = jsonfield.JSONField(default={})
    init_time = models.TimeField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
    init_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.utcnow, editable=False)
```

Project makes use of Django REST Framework and now there's a requirement to filter records by certain date (not a range) considering timezones. That is - in a request timezone of a user along with filter 'init_date' are sent by AngularJS (not pretty sure how exactly) and backend gives response with appropriate data.
So in any case as i can see the challenge is that some records will be not included in response just because they don't have that filter 'init_date'.
Is there any way to achieve that desirable behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose a user in Tokyo (UTC+9) is requesting data from 2016-03-17. That *is* a range: `2016-03-17 00:00:00 +0900` to `2016-03-17 23:59:59 +0900`. So all you need to do is convert those start and end dates to UTC before hitting the database: `2016-03-16 15:00:00` to `2016-03-17 14:59:59`.

edit: rereading your question, what do you mean by

> So in any case as i can see the challenge is that some records will be not included in response just because they don't have that filter 'init_date'. Is there any way to achieve that desirable behaviour?

How do some records not have an `init_date` value set? And what is the desired behavior?

Comment: I meant that they will have ANOTHER init_date that differs from requested but your answer clarifies what i have to do fully. Thanks!